# How to get NTID in a service layer from IIS in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Some background, I built my first .Net Core 2.0 API app that is hosted in a company intranet and used only by internal employees.  The app needs to know who the user is on all pages, to work properly, but we don't want to add login/logout/authentication/sessions since the information doesn't need to be secured, it's only to personalize the user's data.  I have enabled Windows Authentication successfully and I'm seeing the username (DOMAIN/USERNAME) displayed to the screen when I use the following in a controller:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

However, I wanted to get the same username (NTID) in my UserService instead, so that anytime the username is needed, any of the Services can call UserService to get the username.

I have tried all of the following in my UserService, but none of them provide the NTID from IIS:

```
...
return WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
...
return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.ToString();
...
return Environment.UserName;
....
```

Since this is a REST API, I won't be using Views (I'm aware you can get the username in the View).

Is there an easy approach to get the username outside of the controller?  I have found multiple examples online but they are all for < .Net Core 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In core, `HttpContext` is *injected* now, instead of being a thread static. That means the old style of using a static accessor like what you're trying won't work.

To access the `HttpContext` in something it is not automatically injected into (like a controller), you need to inject `IHttpContextAccessor`. For example:

```
public class UserService
{
    protected readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public UserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, as long as you register your service via the ASP.NET Core DI container, an instance will be injected automatically into your service. You can then simply do:

```
var username = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar!  That worked great, thank you for the clear explanation and sample code.  I wanted to add that to anyone else coming to this answer, in order to inject the container into my service I had to add these lines in Startup.cs to my ConfigureServices method: services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();